# Accessing the structure field in unique_ptr causes access violation

Tags: c++

I have a class like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Store {

private:
    struct pointNode {
        T data;
        std::unique_ptr<pointNode> next;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<pointNode> head; 
public:
    Store() : head(nullptr) {}
    Store(const T& data);
    

};
```

Trying to create a constructor that is an example of T data

```
template <typename T>
Store<T>::Store(const T& data) {
    head->data = data;
}
```

But I can't access head->data and head->next in it .I can't figure out what's wrong, I'm just learning to work with unique_ptr,so I probably don't understand something.I would be grateful for your help.
The code that causes the error.

Exception thrown: write access violation.

```
Store<int> a(5);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*I can't access `head->data`*"? Do you get compiler error? Does your program crash?

Comment: This is very unclear. What is the relationship between `Store` and `Stack`? How are you instantiating these templates?

Comment: @molbdnilo forgot to change the name

Comment: @Yksisarvinen writing this  head->data and a hint pops up:<unknown><unnamed>::data

Comment: @Вячеслав It sounds like an intellisense (or how it's named in your IDE) problem. Do you actually get an error while compiling?

Comment: If it's a code completion problem, that's normal.

Comment: @bolov yes,if i write Stack<int> a(5); then then there will be compile error

Comment: @Вячеслав please [edit] your question to include code that produces this compiler error.  [There is no compiler error](https://godbolt.org/z/6EabK4) in the code you've shown us.

Comment: you need to post a [MRE] that we can copy paste in our compiler and see the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Store(const T&)` constructor is not creating a `pointNode` object to be held by the `std::unique_ptr<pointNode>` of the `head` member. The default `std::unique_ptr` constructor will set `head` to `nullptr`, so it never points to an actual object. Thus accessing `head->data` is **undefined behavior**.

Construct the `head` using [`std::make_unique()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique), like so:

```cpp
Store() = delete; // or default if you need it
Store(const T& data) : head(std::make_unique<pointNode>()) {
    head->data = data;
}
```

Comment: Even better, give `pointNode` a constructor that takes a `T` as input, and then you can do this: `struct pointNode { T data; std::unique_ptr<pointNode> next; pointNode(const T &data) : data(data) {} }; ... Store(const T& data) : head(std::make_unique<pointNode>(data)) {}` That way, `head->data` gets constructed and intialized in one go, not default-constructed and then copy-assigned separately.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Your edit improves on the text, but I'm at a loss to understand why you removed the initialisation of `head` in `Store::Store()`. This seems like a source of problems OP was describing. In fact, I think the Copy constructor should just call the default constructor.

Comment: @bitmask `unique_ptr` has a default constructor that will initialize the held pointer to `nullptr`, and that constructor will get called automatically if no constructor is called explicitly, so calling `head(nullptr)` is redundant. `Store() = default;` will generate code that is equivalent to `Store() : head() {}` for you. The OP's problem is not about HOW a `nullptr` is assigned to `head`, but that a `nullptr` is assigned to `head` AT ALL. And no, `Store`'s copy constructor should not call `unique_ptr`'s default constructor when calling `unique_ptr`'s move constructor is more efficient.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Uhm, my point was that in my original post, before your edit, I specificially changed the OP's code from `Store() : head(nullptr) {}` to `Store() : head(std::make_unique<pointNode>()) {}`. You `default`ing `Store()` means that it is again (erroneously) initialised with a `nullptr` -- the specific thing that was the problem in OP's question.

Comment: ... therefore I changed the answer back regarding that point.

Comment: @bitmask Ideally, a default-constructed `Store` should not have any nodes in it, thus `head` should be `nullptr`, whereas a `Store` initialized with `data` should initialize `head` to point at a valid node. This is typical behavior for most linked-list implementations.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm sorry, apparently *my own* head was suffering from a `nullptr` two weeks ago. You were absolutely right and my remarks were incorrect. I think I mistook the problem as a pimpl problem instead of a list problem.